# Spring not recognizing entity parameters

Tags: java, spring

Please what is the reason for this error

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Collection com.Vportal.data.reposito
ry.VisitRequestRepository.findBystaff_name(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Staff! Traversed path: VisitRequest.staff.
```

gotten after running web app in spring?

**`staff.java`**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Staff {

    @Id
    private int staff_id;
    private String staff_name;
    private String staff_email;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = VisitRequest.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "staff")
    private List<VisitRequest> visitRequest;


    public String getstaff_name()
    {
        return staff_name;
    }
    public void setStaff_name(String staff_name)
    {
        this.staff_name = staff_name;
    }
    public String getstaff_email()
    {
        return staff_email;
    }
    public void setStaff_email(String staff_email)
    {
        this.staff_email = staff_email;
    }

    public void setstaff_id(int staff_id)
    {
        this.staff_id = staff_id;
    }
    public int getstaff_id()
    {
        return staff_id;
    }


**
```

**`VisitRequest.java`**

```
@Entity
public class VisitRequest {
    @Id
    private String token;
    private String comment;
    private Date timestamp;
    private boolean status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "staff_name", referencedColumnName = "staff_name",nullable = false)
    private Staff staff;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Visitor_id")
    private Visitor visitor;



    public String getToken(){
        return token;
    }
    public void setToken(String token){
        this.token = token;
    }
    public String getComment(){
        return comment;
    }
    public void setComment(String comment){
        this.comment = comment;
    }
    public Date getTimestamp(){
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp){
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

`VisitRequestRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface VisitRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<VisitRequest, Long> {

    Collection<VisitRequest> findBystaff_name (String staff_name);
}
```

I've tried changing the attributes of my entities, changing the methods in the repositories but i just keep getting the same error. is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Query derivation heavily relies on Java naming conventions. But you're violating them all over the place. Don't, and everything will become easier. Rename your Staff fields to id, name, and email. Remove all the getters and setters and make your IDE regenerate them. Then rename your method (again respecting the Java naming conventions) to findByStaffName

Comment: Your `VisitRequest` doesn't have a property `staff_name` it has a property `staff` which has a property `staff_name`. So if anything you should a finder named `findBystaff_staff_name`. Also your mapping is weird? Why would you map on the `staff_name` instead of the `id`?

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in comments you should fix your labels for example from `staff_name` to `staffName`. But if you really want to stick with  the name `staff_name`. 
Than you can use this:

```java
@Repository
public interface VisitRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<VisitRequest, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT vr FROM VisitRequest vr WHERE vr.staff.staff_name = ?1")
    Collection<VisitRequest> findIt (String staff_name);
}
```

Or

```java
@Repository
public interface VisitRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<VisitRequest, Long> {

    Collection<VisitRequest> findStaffStaff_name(String staff_name);
}
```

And change naming in getter and setter in `Staff`, but if you use `lombok.Data` then you do not need this code (lombok will generate it).